# Sending Reports generated by SpecFlow+Runner in Email

Tags: c#, email, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm running Tests in Specflow+Runner (Selenium c#).After execution Test Reports are generated.
I need to send generated reports to Email. Is there any specific way to send reports to email after completion of test run ?

Comment: As it stands we do not have enough information to answer your question. How are you running tests? Are you on Windows or MacOS? Which version of SpecFlow are you using? Which unit test runner are you using?

Comment: By "send the reports to email" --- what do you mean? Please provide some specifics for what this e-mail should look like, or the information it should have.

Comment: And finally, what have you tried so far?